# How does knitr inject TeX code into the document?

Tags: r, knitr

I'm very new to knitr. How do I write R code in knitr that composes LaTeX from scratch and injects it into the document at a particular point?

I'm thinking of something similar to what PHP or JSP does.

Comment: To answer the title's question, knitr is "simply" an R function that turns a quasi-LaTeX document into a .tex file.

Answer (score 2):

TeX is a text for `knitr`, so you can use any text-generating function, e.g. `cat()`.  To include the text into the document, add `echo=FALSE, results='asis'` to the chunk options, e.g.

```
<<echo=FALSE,results="asis">>=
title="Introduction"
cat(paste("\\section{",title,"}",sep=""))
@
```

which adds to your document `\section{Introduction}`

Comment: Which example provides the answer to the question? I did not find it.

Comment: Try https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-minimal.Rnw

Comment: I asked for a way for knitr to compose LaTeX *code* (i.e. markup) and add it to the document.

Comment: Sorry, did not understand your quesiton.  Please see update.